# A confusing case about prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm learning JS OOP stuff, and found a confusing case to me. In the following snippet of code, I use `Object.create` method to realize the inheritance.

```
function Parent(){
    this.name = "wang";
}
function Child(){
   this.age = 28;
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
var mychild = new Child();
console.log(mychild.name)
```

The `mychild.name` is undefined.

But is I use `new Parent()` to do the inheritance part, it can work as following:

```
function Parent(){
    this.name = "wang";
}
function Child(){
    this.age = 28;
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
var mychild = new Child();
console.log(mychild.name)
```

I once read some tutorial, which said that in fact the `Object.create` method is correct way to follow. So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is correct for inheritance, however it's important to note that you haven't called the `Parent` function on the newly created `Child` instance.

To do that, you can use `call` or `apply`:

```
function Child() {
  Parent.call(this)
  this.age = 28
}
```

```js
function Parent(){
    this.name = "wang";
}
function Child(){
    Parent.call(this);
    this.age = 28;
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
var mychild = new Child();
console.log(mychild.name);
```

If you're using ES2015, you can use `class` to simplify the code:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "wang"
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.age = 28
  }
}

const mychild = new Child()
console.log(mychild.name)
```

Note that in the later example, `super` takes the place of `Parent.call(this)`.

Comment: I can think of the 'apply or call' solution . But the prototype inheritance said that if can't find the `name` property in `Child`, then will try to find `name` property in Child's prototype `Parent`. Now I already set up the prototype relationship, why it can't work? That's my confusing point in fact.

Comment: @ChrisBao, if you don't call `Parent`, how is it possible to have a `name` property set anywhere in the prototype chain? `Parent.prototype` doesn't have a `name` property set, and `Object.create` knows nothing about the `Parent` function.

Comment: More importantly, if you set `Child.prototype.name` (whether from instantiating via `new Parent()` or setting it manually as `Child.prototype.name = "wang"`) every instance of `Child` will reference that shared value, rather than having their own individual value. In your example, it makes no difference, but once you start taking parameters for those functions it will matter significantly.